# How to solve Non-comparable types found while sorting: Cannot compare xs:date with xs:integer - XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

How to solve Non-comparable types found while sorting: Cannot compare xs:date with xs:integer This line showing error `O&#x2019;Connor v Uber Technols., Inc. (ND Cal, Dec. 05, 2013, No. C&#x2013;13&#x2013;3826 EMC) 2013 US Dist Lexis 171813, rev&#x2019;d on other grounds (9th Cir 2018) 904 F3d 1087:` This line comes two times parenthesis (ND Cal, Dec. 05, 2013, No. C–13–3826 EMC) and (9th Cir 2018). Can we take first Parentheses. And last two entry not move descendant according to latest date becouse regex is use for Date format `\((.*?)((' || string-join($months, '|') || ')\. ([0-9]{1,2}), ([0-9]{4})).*?\)`
**Input XML**

```
  <root>
    <p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">AFL-CIO v Unemployment Ins. Appeals Bd. (1994) 23 CA4th 51:</named-content></p>
    <p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">AFL-CIO v Unemployment Ins. Appeals Bd. (1996) 13 C4th 1017:</named-content></p>
    <p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Ambat v City &#x0026; County of San Francisco (ND Cal 2010) 693 F Supp 2d 1130, rev&#x2019;d on other grounds (9th Cir 2014) 757 F3d 1017:</named-content></p>
    <p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Ambat v City &#x0026; County of San Francisco (9th Cir 2014) 757 F3d 1017:</named-content></p>
    <p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Anaheim Union High Sch. Dist. (2016) PERB Dec. No. 2504E, 41 PERC 80:</named-content></p>
    <p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Anaheim Union High Sch. Dist. (1981) PERB Dec. No. 0177E, 5 PERC 12148:</named-content></p>
    <p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Artec Group v Klimov (ND Cal, Nov. 22, 2015) 2015 US Dist Lexis 171698:</named-content></p>
    <p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Artec Group v Klimov (ND Cal, Dec. 22, 2015) 2016 US Dist Lexis 170194:</named-content></p>
    <p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">O&#x2019;Connor v Uber Technols., Inc. (ND Cal, Dec. 05, 2013, No. C&#x2013;13&#x2013;3826 EMC) 2013 US Dist Lexis 171813, rev&#x2019;d on other grounds 904 F3d 1087:</named-content></p>
    <p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">O&#x2019;Connor v Uber Technols., Inc. (2018) 904 F3d 1087:</named-content></p>
    <p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">O&#x2019;Connor v Uber Technols., Inc. (ND Cal 2015) 82 F Supp 3d 1133:</named-content></p>
    <p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Swarmfly, Inc. v Cloudflare, Inc. (ND Cal, May 31, 2018, No. C 17-06957 WHA) 2018 US Dist Lexis 91333:</named-content></p>
    <p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Swarmify, Inc. v Cloudflare, Inc. (ND Cal, Sept. 28, 2018, No. C 17-06957 WHA) 2018 US Dist Lexis 168317:</named-content></p>
    <p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Swarmify, Inc. v Cloudflare, Inc. (ND Cal, Mar. 3, 2018, No. C 17-06597 WHA) 2018 WL 112204:</named-content></p>
    <p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Zody v Microsoft Corp. (ND Cal, June 7, 2013, No. C&#x2013;12&#x2013;00942&#x2013;YGR) 2013 US Dist Lexis 80623:</named-content></p>
    <p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Zody v Microsoft Corp. (ND Cal, July 24, 2013, No. C&#x2013;12&#x2013;00942&#x2013;YGR) 2013 US Dist Lexis 103868:</named-content></p>
</root>
```

**XSLT**

```
    <xsl:param name="months" as="xs:string*"
    select="'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'"/>

<xsl:param name="date-pattern" as="xs:string"
    select="'\((.*?)((' || string-join($months, '|') || ')\. ([0-9]{1,2}), ([0-9]{4})).*?\)'"/>

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="@specific-use|named-content[@content-type='emSecs']"/>    

<xsl:function name="mf:extract-date" as="xs:date?">
    <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:sequence
        select="let $match := analyze-string($input, $date-pattern)/*:match[1]
        return 
        if ($match) 
        then xs:date(
        $match//*:group[@nr = 5] 
        || '-' || format-integer(index-of($months, $match//*:group[@nr = 3]), '00') 
        || '-' || format-integer($match//*:group[@nr = 4], '00'))
        else ()"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:function name="mf:extract-year" as="xs:integer?">
    <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:sequence
        select="analyze-string($input, '\((.*?)([0-9]{4})\)')/*:match[1]/*:group[@nr = 2]"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:function name="mf:extract-sort" as="xs:string?">
    <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:sequence
        select="analyze-string($input, '\((.*?)\)')/*:match[1]/*:group[@nr = 1]"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="p" group-adjacent="substring-before(named-content[@content-type = 'emEntry'], '(')">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                <xsl:sort select="let $year := mf:extract-year(.)
                    return if ($year) then -$year else 1"/>
                <xsl:sort select="let $date := mf:extract-date(.)
                    return if (exists($date)) then $date else 1" order="descending"/>
                <xsl:sort select="let $sort := mf:extract-sort(.)
                    return if ($sort) then $sort else 1" order="descending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

**Expected Output**

```
<root>
   <p content-type="emCase">
      <named-content content-type="emEntry">AFL-CIO v Unemployment Ins. Appeals Bd. (1996) 13 C4th 1017:</named-content>
   </p>
   <p content-type="emCase">
      <named-content content-type="emEntry">AFL-CIO v Unemployment Ins. Appeals Bd. (1994) 23 CA4th 51:</named-content>
   </p>
   <p content-type="emCase">
      <named-content content-type="emEntry">Ambat v City &amp; County of San Francisco (9th Cir 2014) 757 F3d 1017:</named-content>
   </p>
   <p content-type="emCase">
      <named-content content-type="emEntry">Ambat v City &amp; County of San Francisco (ND Cal 2010) 693 F Supp 2d 1130, rev’d on other grounds (9th Cir 2014) 757 F3d 1017:</named-content>
   </p>
   <p content-type="emCase">
      <named-content content-type="emEntry">Anaheim Union High Sch. Dist. (2016) PERB Dec. No. 2504E, 41 PERC 80:</named-content>
   </p>
   <p content-type="emCase">
      <named-content content-type="emEntry">Anaheim Union High Sch. Dist. (1981) PERB Dec. No. 0177E, 5 PERC 12148:</named-content>
   </p>
   <p content-type="emCase">
      <named-content content-type="emEntry">Artec Group v Klimov (ND Cal, Dec. 22, 2015) 2016 US Dist Lexis 170194:</named-content>
   </p>
   <p content-type="emCase">
      <named-content content-type="emEntry">Artec Group v Klimov (ND Cal, Nov. 22, 2015) 2015 US Dist Lexis 171698:</named-content>
   </p>
   <p content-type="emCase">
      <named-content content-type="emEntry">O’Connor v Uber Technols., Inc. (2018) 904 F3d 1087:</named-content>
   </p>
   <p content-type="emCase">
      <named-content content-type="emEntry">O’Connor v Uber Technols., Inc. (ND Cal 2015) 82 F Supp 3d 1133:</named-content>
   </p>
   <p content-type="emCase">
      <named-content content-type="emEntry">O’Connor v Uber Technols., Inc. (ND Cal, Dec. 05, 2013, No. C–13–3826 EMC) 2013 US Dist Lexis 171813, rev’d on other grounds (9th Cir 2018) 904 F3d 1087:</named-content>
   </p>
   <p content-type="emCase">
      <named-content content-type="emEntry">Swarmify, Inc. v Cloudflare, Inc. (ND Cal, Sept. 28, 2018, No. C 17-06957 WHA) 2018 US Dist Lexis 168317:</named-content>
   </p>
   <p content-type="emCase">
      <named-content content-type="emEntry">Swarmfly, Inc. v Cloudflare, Inc. (ND Cal, May 31, 2018, No. C 17-06957 WHA) 2018 US Dist Lexis 91333:</named-content>
   </p>
   <p content-type="emCase">
      <named-content content-type="emEntry">Swarmify, Inc. v Cloudflare, Inc. (ND Cal, Mar. 3, 2018, No. C 17-06597 WHA) 2018 WL 112204:</named-content>
   </p>
   <p content-type="emCase">
      <named-content content-type="emEntry">Zody v Microsoft Corp. (ND Cal, July 24, 2013, No. C–12–00942–YGR) 2013 US Dist Lexis 103868:</named-content>
   </p>
   <p content-type="emCase">
      <named-content content-type="emEntry">Zody v Microsoft Corp. (ND Cal, June 7, 2013, No. C–12–00942–YGR) 2013 US Dist Lexis 80623:</named-content>
   </p>
</root>
```

**CODE**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmC4Jf/19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let $date := mf:extract-date(.) return if (exists($date)) then $date else 1` is probably the culprit, you will need to use some default `xs:date`, not sure which base date you need but you can use e.g. `else xs:date('1900-01-01')`.

As for the month name matching, I am not sure the previous approach works fine if we use regular expression patterns for the month names, but if we use an additional function

```
<xsl:param name="months" as="xs:string*"
    select="'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'June?', 'July?', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'"/>

<xsl:param name="date-pattern" as="xs:string"
    select="'\((.*?)((' || string-join($months, '|') || ')\. ([0-9]{1,2}), ([0-9]{4})).*?\)'"/>

<xsl:function name="mf:index-of-match" as="xs:integer*">
    <xsl:param name="patterns" as="xs:string*"/>
    <xsl:param name="month-match" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:sequence
      select="for $pos in (1 to count($patterns))
              return $pos[matches($month-match, $patterns[$pos])]"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:function name="mf:extract-date" as="xs:date?">
    <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:sequence
        select="let $match := analyze-string($input, $date-pattern)/*:match[1]
        return 
        if ($match) 
        then xs:date(
        $match//*:group[@nr = 5] 
        || '-' || format-integer(mf:index-of-match($months, $match//*:group[@nr = 3]), '00') 
        || '-' || format-integer($match//*:group[@nr = 4], '00'))
        else ()"/>
</xsl:function>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmC4Jf/20 it might offer more flexibility.

Comment: Martin Sir Thanks for the reply. If `let $date := mf:extract-date(.) return if (exists($date)) then $date else 1` replace to ` let $date := mf:extract-date(.) return if (exists($date)) then $date xs:date('1900-01-01')` error solve. But Complete Date function not working proper (eg. `June 7, 2013` or `May. 7, 2013`). Because month after punctuation problem last two line. Latest Complete date s/b decedent order.

Comment: Martin Sir, I have used `<xsl:param name="months" as="xs:string*"
        select="'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'"/>`. But my last two entry month full name (e.g.` June` or  `July`).

Comment: @Sandy, see whether the edit helps for the month parsing and matching.

Comment: Martin Sir, last two entry s/b change `Zody v Microsoft Corp. (ND Cal, June 7, 2013, No. ` latest Date s/b descending order to acceding order sequence. Can we modified regex `<xsl:param name="date-pattern" as="xs:string"
        select="'\((.*?)((' || string-join($months, '|') || ')\. ([0-9]{1,2}), ([0-9]{4})).*?\)'"/>` because the problem is after month period eg. (`ND Cal, June 7, 2013` or `ND Cal, Sept. 28, 2018,`).

Comment: @Sandy, try to adapt the code to handle the format variations you expect. I think I did already suggest on a previous question that it might be easier to run the input first through some date normalization transformation step that ensures all entries use the same date format before later on going to sort.

Comment: Thanks, Martin Sir for the help.